# Issues with 1st order differential equation (integrating factor)

Tags: calculus, differential

I've tried it a few times and I keep coming up with a different answer to the textbook.

The problem is:
$2\frac{dy}{dx} - 10xy - 5x = 0$

I have come up with $y = Ce^{-\frac{5x^2}{2}}$

Whereas the textbook says it should be:
$y = -\frac{1}{2} + Ce^{\frac{5x^2}{2}}$

I'm not sure how its coming up with this answer when dividing by the integrating factor of $e^{\frac{5x^2}{2}}$ to get $y$ on its own.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your process?

Comment: 2dy/dx-10xy-5x=0 to 2dy/dx-10xy=5x to dy/dx-5xy=5x/2. P(x) = -5x, Q(x) = 5x/2. found I(x) = e^(integral of P(x) which came out as e^((-5x^2)/2). From there I plugged in I(x) to the linear differential so that it became e^((-5x^2)/2)*dy/dx - 5x*e^((-5x^2)/2)*y = 5x/2*e^((-5x^2)/2).  I found the integral of both sides using integration by substitution: e^((-5x^2)/2)*y = -e^((-5x^2)/2)+C. And finally solved for y resulting in y = Ce^((-5x^2)/2). Looking back at it again I think I have made a mistake when solving for y not accounting for the negative power.

Comment: I have realised my mistakes. When integrating the RHS I didn't substitute properly resulting in no -1/2. And then when solving for y I didn't account for the division by a negative power resulting in a positive power.

Comment: Next time, place your attempt in the body of the post by editing it, and please use MathJax.